# Firefox 4.0 Theming

Tags: 10.10, firefox, themes

I am dual booting Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat and Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop. And I have installed the latest Firefox 4.0 on both the operating system. However when I click the organize tab button on windows, I can see the firefox personna theme applied in the background as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Firefox 4.0 - Windows 7]

And here is it installed in ubuntu 10.10

[image: Firefox 4.0 - Ubuntu 10.10]

As you can see from both the screenshots, the firefox 4.0 theme in ubuntu cannot be seen under the organize tabs page. Also the firefox button is missing in the ubuntu 10.10 system. Although the theme can be seen in ubuntu when browsing the web. It is only in the tab organization page that I dont see the firefox personna theme applied but just a dull grey background.

**Update**: I am running firefox 4.0 final version in windows 7 and firefox 4.0 RC in ubuntu 10.10 installed using the firefox-next ppa.

**Update**: I have submitted a feedback as suggested by ændrük. :)

**Update**: I tried it on the latest stable release of firefox 4.0 (downloaded from their website) and still have this problem.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have something to do with the fact that the actual window decoration is not themed by the persona. It would look out of place and it would probably be by design that it isn't themed?